# Dotnet 3.1 Stripe :The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: .net-core, openssl, stripe-payments, centos7

I implemented stripe payment gateway, its working on my local system, but not working on production server which is a `CentOs7` based on Linux server.

My code is given:
[HttpPost]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentUsingStripe(string stripeToken, string stripeEmail, double price, int companyid)
{
  try
  {
    var config = await _dbContext.SuperAdminConfiguration.Select(x => new { x.StripeSecret }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (config != null)
      StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = config.StripeSecret;

    var company = await _dbContext.Companies.Include(c => c.CompanyConfiguration).Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.CompanyId == companyid).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (company == null)
    {
      return NotFound();
    }
    var myCharge = new Stripe.ChargeCreateOptions();

    myCharge.Amount = (long)price;
    myCharge.Currency = "USD";
    myCharge.ReceiptEmail = stripeEmail;
    myCharge.Description = company.Name;
    myCharge.Source = stripeToken;
    myCharge.Capture = true;
    var chargeService = new Stripe.ChargeService();
    Charge stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(myCharge);
    if (stripeCharge.Status != "failed")
    {
     // further my application logic
```

Stack traced:

```
 Web.Areas.SuperAdminPortal.Controllers.IdentificationController[0]
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I tried `dotnet` cert commands , created `dotnet certifactes`,  re-newed the `SSL` on `nginx` but not working... also run it on HTTP and HTTPs but throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

NET Core 3.1 is end-of-life for over a year now : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-1#long-term-support

Being so old, it didn't relaibly support TLSv1.2, which is a requirement for making API calls to Stripe. Their recommendation was to update to NET Core 4.5

I'd suggest updating to a supported/modern/secure platform, especially for code where you're going to handling customer data.

https://stripe.com/blog/completing-tls-upgrade

https://archive.is/If4Jq

Comment: So why is it working on local?

Comment: maybe your local machine runs newer dependencies and network stacks.

Comment: i tried it on docker also... on docker its working fine.